# Command works on terminal but doesn't work in cron

Tags: cron

I have the following command that I can run from any folder and it will start my (Angularjs) webapp by using the grunt task runner tool -

```
cd /root/dev/myapp && grunt serve
```

However when I put it in cron it doesn't work -

```
*/1 * * * * cd /root/dev/myapp && grunt serve
```

Any ideas on why it is not working?

Comment: The most common problem with cron is cron runs with a minimal shell and minimal environmental variables. Use the full path to scripts, `/root/dev/myapp/grunt serve` depends on what "grunt" is exactly. You may need to put it in a more standard location such as /usr/local

Comment: Just copped it as you posted!

Answer (score 2):

I had to set the path to grunt -

```
*/1 * * * * cd /root/dev/myapp && /usr/bin/local/grunt serve
```